# Active Model Serializer conflicts with Active storage while streaming active storage blobs

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, active-model-serializers

I want to download all the attachments by streaming them using `ActionController:: Live`. It's working fine if I remove `gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.9.2'` gem. It halts the server and I have to restart it.

Here is the controller

zip_streaming.rb

```rb
    class ZipStreamingController < ApplicationController
      include ActionController::Live
    
      def download
        zipname = 'test_archive.zip'
        send_file_headers!(
          type: "application/zip",
          disposition: "attachment",
          filename: zipname
        )
        response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.httpdate.to_s
        response.headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
    
        writer = ZipTricks::BlockWrite.new do |chunk|
          response.stream.write(chunk)
        end
    
        ZipTricks::Streamer.open(writer) do |zip|
          Model.all.each do |model|
            model.image.each do |i|
              zip.write_deflated_file("#{model.name}/#{i.filename.to_s}") do |file_writer|
                i.blob.download do |chunk|
                  file_writer << chunk
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      ensure
        response.stream.close
      end
    end
```

model.rb

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :image
end
```

Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'zip_tricks', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.9.2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `active_model_serializers` gem, I have changed the version to `0.10.1` and its working fine now.

Found the solution here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25672#issuecomment-230376105